# Problems filling DataTables with variable data/table headers

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm trying to populate my DataTables report dynamically. My code also dynamically generates the necessary table headers, based on the data for DataTables.

When I hardcode a table in my index.html, my table gets populated just fine. However, when I generate a table for my index using JavaScript, I get a working table, but it won't get populated. There are no errors in the console and the object with data for my table is filled correctly.

I've tried use a if/else loop to populate the report only when it has been generated.

Also I split the code up in two functions, running the function to fill the report only after the function to generate the report has finished.

Both tries failed.

What do I have to do to generate a report and fill it once it has been finished?

**Code:**

```
function rapport_vullen(){
// generate the report
arrayForHeader = (Object.keys(geojson.features[0].properties))

var genereerTabel = '<table id="report" class="table table-striped table-bordered">';
    genereerTabel += '<thead><tr>'
        for (i= 0; i < arrayForHeader.length; i++){
            genereerTabel += '<th>'+arrayForHeader[i]+'</th>'
        }
    genereerTabel += '</tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>'

$("#test").html(genereerTabel);
$('#report').DataTable(); 

// fill the report
    arrayTwee = [];
    arrayTwee = arrayTwee.concat(Object.keys(geojson.features[0].properties));
    arrayDrie = arrayTwee.map(function(d) {return {data: d};});
    console.log(arrayDrie);

    $("#rapport").dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        "aaData": geojson.features.map(function(row) { return row.properties; }),
        "columns": arrayDrie
    });
};
```

Comment: You have `$("#rapport")` instead of `$('#report')`.

Comment: I feel like an idiot... That what you get for coding in both English & Dutch. Thanks a million, been pulling my hair out all day.